# Mostrar PDF na pagina via Servlet

Tags: java, aplicação-web, pdf, servlet, request

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web usando Servlets e JSPs. Ainda não possuo muita experiência com isso.

A minha pagina contém um botão que faz um download de um arquivo do BD e um `<object>` HTML para exibir um PDF que está no BD.

O botão funciona normalmente, mas o PDF não aparece. Não está aparecendo pois passo como parâmetro o `id` com `request.getParameter("id")`, mas o problema é que não chega a fazer um *request* pra esse meu Servlet.

Para exemplificar, o meu *select* esta assim:

```
SELECT pdf from pdf WHERE id = ?
```

Quando dou um `request.getParameter("id")` e passo o `id` como parâmetro nessa *query* não chega a funcionar, mas se eu mudo a *query* já passando um parâmetro como:

```
SELECT pdf from pdf WHERE id = 1
```

Então o PDF carrega na página.

Resumindo: Tenho uma JSP, que contém apenas um botão que faz um *request* pra um Servlet pra baixar um arquivo do BD. Funciona perfeitamente e tenho um `<object>` para exibir um PDF que também está armazenado no BD, mas esse não funciona como expliquei.

O que acho que pode estar acontecendo é que o botão funciona pois quando dou `submit` ele faz a requisição ao Servlet, mas o PDF já é pra estar carregado na tela quando a página abrir e não tenho ainda muita experiência com programação Java para a WEB, não estou conseguindo fazer uma requisição ao Servlet quando a página carregar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso? Preciso de alguma função em JavaScript ou algo similar para fazer a requisição e passar o parâmetro para meu Servlet do PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exibir um PDF na página usando `<object>` você **não** deve gerar o PDF ao renderizar a página. Apenas crie uma URL para a página que gera o PDF.

Exemplo:

```
<object data="/ver-pdf/?id=123" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

Quando o navegador encontrar essa *tag* em sua página ele irá fazer uma nova requisição para o servidor e então uma página exclusivamente responsável por gerar o PDF e devolver para o navegador entrará em ação.

Essa página é exatamente igual à de *download*, porém sem os cabeçalhos geralmente usado para forçar o navegador a baixar o arquivo.

Comment: Fiz como falou, mas ainda nao obtive resultados

Comment: Pode postar um exemplo de como deveria ser o codigo do Servlet para a resposta? Sem os Cabecalhos? –

Comment: Consegui. Na verdade um pouco diferente, mas me ajudou muito sua resposta! Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @henrique Que bom que conseguiu. Desculpe não ter retornado antes, mas estou em outro fuso. Abraço.

Comment: Se você pudesse postar sua resposta seria bom, estou com a mesma difuldade